# jQuery Adding Child Elements to Newly Created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am running into a problem with some jQuery. I am attempting to append HTML to a newly create element using a jQuery foreach loop, but it seems to not be working. Basically, the goal is to generate list of links dynamically from a Javascript array. Step one is to make the list item (<`li`>) and then append an anchor (`<a href="...">`) to the newly created li. But it is only generating the list items and not appending the anchor.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```js
    // Define the Array
    pages = ["page1.php", "page2.php", "page3.php"]
    // Loop through each page
    pages.forEach(function(page) {
        // Build the first li and give it a unique id
        $("#sidelinks").append($("<li class='nav-item' id='navlink-"+pages.indexOf(page)+"'></li>"));
        // Store the newly create li as a var
        var newLink = $("#navlink-" + pages.indexOf(page));
        // Append the anchor to the newly create li
        newLink.html("<a href='" + page + "' class='nav-link text-dark font-italic>Introduction</a>");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sidelinks">
</ul>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure why people still use jQuery. It seems to complicate things more than anything. That would be so straight forward in vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems missing `'` causes the problem

```
class='nav-link text-dark font-italic>Introduction</a>");
                                     ^ (') missing here
```

```js
// Define the Array
pages = ["page1.php", "page2.php", "page3.php"]
// Loop through each page
pages.forEach(function(page) {
  // Build the first li and give it a unique id
  $("#sidelinks").append($("<li class='nav-item' id='navlink-" + pages.indexOf(page) + "'></li>"));
  // Store the newly create li as a var
  var newLink = $("#navlink-" + pages.indexOf(page));
  // Append the anchor to the newly create li
  newLink.html("<a href='" + page + "' class='nav-link text-dark font-italic'>Introduction</a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sidelinks">
</ul>
```

Comment: Dang, that was it! Thanks for the second pair of eyes